# Securely storing encryption key in session?

Tags: php, apache, encryption, mysqli, key-storage

I have a web app that requires a user to register and enter some personal data.

On registration, a master key is generated that is then encrypted using a password derived key and stored in the database. When the user logs in, the master key is decrypted and used to decrypt the user’s data.

Where is the best place to store the decrypted master key so that the user doesn’t have to re-enter a password every time their data needs accessing?

My thoughts on this at the moment are this:

1. User logs in and password derived key used to decrypt the master key
2. New random key generated and used to encrypt master key
3. Store newly encrypted master key in database sessions table
4. Store newly generated random key in a cookie in the users browser set to expire at the end of session / logout.

The web app is hosted by a 3rd party so I don’t have the option of creating encrypted partitions etc.

Can anyone suggest a better way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: This question seems opinion-based / too broad.

Comment: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption -- see: `KeyProtectedByPassword`. You can decrypt it into `$_SESSION` and then, so long as you're using HTTPS and configure your server well, you're fine against common threat models. If you have a paranoid threat model, you probably shouldn't be hosted by a 3rd party at all.